# Date format of sql from regional settings

Tags: c#, sql, date-format, regional-settings

I am reading date from the sql table. In sql table date time in the format how client set in regional format. Because of this reading date and splitting that and taking to a format what we want is becoming difficult. Is there any way to restrict sql date format from regional settings date format (means sql not suppose to take regional settings date format).

Now i got the answer:

```
string Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeString).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string time = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeString).ToString("hh:mm:ss");

//dateTimeString--->my dateTime value from sql database
```

Comment: What date type is the column you are storing the date in?

Comment: What language are you using for you application?

Answer (score 1):

If you write datetime fields using [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) there should be no problem.

That way, dates get formatted like "2011-09-26T12:04:00", so there's no misunderstanding possible.